# How cast from Float in object array to float variable?

Tags: java, android

Hi I retrieve data and one Float value from sqlite and return in arraylist:

```
if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            do
            {
                ....
                rowArray.add(cursor.getFloat(2));
                ....
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

Problem occurred in float cast, when I try to set float variable from the list:

```
ArrayList<Object> row;
        row = db.getNameAsArray(name);

        mCurrentPrice=((Float)row.get(2)).floatValue();
```

There is no error but app FC in this line. Simple float cast doesnt work neither.
Thx for any answer.

Logcat:

```
02-07 22:34:19.537: ERROR/Retrieve Error(632): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
```

02-07 22:34:21.217: WARN/System.err(632): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
02-07 22:34:21.267: WARN/System.err(632):     at com.testing.retrieveDrinkName(DatabaseActivity.java:222)
02-07 22:34:21.527: WARN/System.err(632):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-07 22:34:21.547: WARN/System.err(632):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 22:34:21.596: WARN/System.err(632):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-07 22:34:21.657: WARN/System.err(632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-07 22:34:21.667: WARN/System.err(632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 22:34:21.737: WARN/System.err(632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-07 22:34:21.769: WARN/System.err(632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-07 22:34:21.797: WARN/System.err(632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-07 22:34:21.817: WARN/System.err(632):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Use logcat to see the error causing the FC.  To see logcat, switch to the DDMS perspective in eclipse or run adb logcat on the command line.

Comment: So, a method named "getNameAsArray" returns float values?  Why?

Comment: method return Array of Doubles, Strings and Floats values.

Comment: logcat show java.lang.ClassCastException java.lang.String

Comment: Since you have an array of `Objects` perhaps you would be better off doing an `instanceof` check before the cast?  My bet is that you are not getting a `Float` object, and are trying to cast something else.  Please provide your logcat output.

Comment: dave.c : logcat added, if I step - in row are right values, and with hard coded mCurrentPrice= (float) 15.4; works everything fine

Comment: What do you mean by "app FC"?  Is it possible that null is being returned in that row?

Comment: I debug this step and there is correct float value in the row, its FC when cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your last comment shows, you are trying to cast a `String` to a `Float`.  Your code doesn't make it clear exactly the problem you are trying to solve, but if you have a `String` value and would like a `float`, you can do:

```
mCurrentPrice = Float.parseFloat(stringValue);
```

Comment: @Hruskozrout Yes, the stacktrace shows that it is a ClassCastException.  You can't turn a String into a float by casting it, you need to use the parse method as dave.c describes.

Comment: Thanks dave.c and Mayra, with dave.c method its works, I was thinking when do rowArray.add(cursor.getFloat(2)); its Float it looks like all row is represented by String values.. I must review my code again. Thanks for your time.

Comment: would the downvoter care to explain how they feel this answer could be improved?